# How to use c byte pointer function's dll in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, dll

I have a dll library which is like

```
void Decrypt(BYTE* RoundKey, BYTE* Data){...}
```

It is a simple decryption function, which receives a key and data pointer and decrypts only the data.
I wanna use this dll in C#, so I wrote a sample test code

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern private static unsafe void decrypt(byte* RoundKey, byte* Data);

static unsafe void Main(string[] args) {
   public static byte[] Key = {0x00, ....};
   public static byte[] data = {0x00, ....};
   decrypt(&Key, &data);
}
```

And this code is not compiling. I want to find out how to use this dll in C#?

Comment: A couple of things... you can't declare a `public static` local variable. Also, method names are case-sensitive, `decrypt` != `Decrypt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write it as follow (assuming dll library knows key and data size):

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static unsafe extern void Decrypt(byte* roundKey, byte* data);

public static byte[] Key = { 0x00, ...};
public static byte[] Data = { 0x00, ... };

static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
       fixed (byte* keyPtr = Key)
       {
              fixed(byte* dataPtr = Data)
              {
                    Decrypt(keyPtr, dataPtr);
              }
       }
}
```